# Progressbar with three sections in Android

Tags: android, progress-bar

I have figured out that we can set a secondary progress for a progress bar in android by defining a custom style like following xml code:

res/drawable/custom_profressbar_horizontal.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>![enter image description here][1]

<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@android:id/background">
      <shape>
                <corners android:radius="15dip" />
                <gradient
                     android:startColor="#ffffffff"
                     android:centerColor="#ffdddddd"
                     android:centerY="0.50"
                     android:endColor="#ffffffff"
                     android:angle="270" />
            </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress">
        <clip>
            <shape>
                <corners android:radius="15dip" />
                <solid android:color="#ec3910"/>
            </shape>
        </clip>
    </item>
    <item android:id="@android:id/progress">
         <clip>
             <shape>
                 <corners   android:radius="15dip" />
                 <gradient android:startColor="#ff0e75af"
                      android:endColor="#ff1997e1"
                      android:angle="90" />
             </shape>
         </clip>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

and in the layout of my Activity i have this:

activity_maib.xml:

```
<ProgressBar
    style="@style/CustomProgressBar"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_margin="7dp"
    android:max="100"
    android:progress="50"
    android:secondaryProgress="80" />
```

and i have this progress bar:

[image]

But i need to have a third progress. how can i do this?

Thanx in advance.

Comment: @ m.taheri, did you get the solution? I'm also trying for the same.